# Java code to send Android App to new activity?

Tags: java, android

Hi I have some java code in my android app using http, I want to send it to a new activity if tv response equals "User Found." Here is that bit of code:

```
tv.setText(""+response);
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this.UserPage.class));
    }
```

My errors are for line:

`if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))` //The method `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` is undefined for the type `HttpResponse`, but I thought this was a method already in Http, I've tried ignore and just `response.("User Found")`

And my other error:

`startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this.UserPage.class));` //Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected, I know that Java identifiers should not be keywords, but if I change class to MyClass or anything else, or just delete it I get more errors. Thanks!

Comment: Get message entity from response convert it tostring then compare `if(response.getEntity().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("user found")`. and pass two parameters in intent constructor separated by comma `new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class)`

Comment: `if(response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserPage.class));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` is a method of the `String` class. You need to convert your `HttpResponse` to a `String` first.
- Use a `,` instead of the second `.`: `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));`, assuming `UserPage` is a subclass of `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you, these errors are fixed. Now in my second activity(UserPage) I want to set the view to a layout I created called user. like this:


    setContentView(R.layout.user);//error:user cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0):

```
 My errors are for line: if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
 //The method equalsIgnoreCase(String) is undefined for the type HttpResponse, 
 but I thought this was a method already in Http, I've tried ignore and 
 just response.("User Found")
```

You should parse your response at first and then compare.

```
 And my other error: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this.UserPage.class));
 //Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected, I know that Java 
 identifiers
 should not be keywords, but if I change class to MyClass or anything else, or 
 just delete it I get more errors. Thanks!
```

startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class)) [Instead of "." you should use "," - I assumed, that UserPage.class is you second Activity]